# Send files to Automator in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, automation, finder, automator

I remember in Tiger, you could always select a bunch of files in Finder and right click them, there was an option to open the selection in Automator. However, it seems that option has been lost somewhere between the Leopard and Snow Leopard upgrade. Or am I a bit blind?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's replaced by *Right-click » Services » Create Workflow*. I can only guess the reason being the redesign of Automator that now usually opens with a sheet prompting you to select a template (application, workflow, etc.).

---

Alternatively, *Finder menu » Services » (development category) » Create Workflow*.

---

If you don't see them go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*, look for the *Development* category and make sure *Create Workflow* is checked.

---

For some reason, the similar *Create Service* menu item does not add a *Get Specified Finder Items* action, probably because services are designed to receive selected files/folders, and the Finder selection is kept.

Comment: @Anriëtte Combrink: If you have accepted this answer, you should also award the bounty by using the Bounty button. These are two different actions - accepting alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

From [Automator workflows broken in 10.6](http://modmyi.com/forums/snow-leopard-10-6/682783-automator-workflows-broken-10-6-fix-inside-thread.html) :

> Automator action workflows are now
>   called "Services". If you want your
>   plugins or workflows to work again,
>   do this......
>
> Here's an example:
>
> If your Finder plug-in workflow
>   doesn’t work,
>
> In SnowLeopard, services provide a
>   powerful method of adding
>   functionality to the Finder and other
>   applications. Services supersede
>   Finder plug-in workflows. If you use
>   Finder plug-in workflows created on an
>   earlier system, you must manually turn
>   them into services.
>
> To create a service from a Finder
>   plug-in workflow:
>
> Open the old Finder plug-in workflow.
>
> Choose File > New.
>
> Select the Services template and click
>   Choose.
>
> Choose the type of data your service
>   requires as input in the “Service
>   receives selected” pop-up menu, and
>   then choose an application from the
>   “in” pop-up menu.
>
> If the service should be available in
>   all applications, choose “any
>   application.”
>
> If you want the service to behave
>   exactly the way the previous Finder
>   plug-in workflow did, choose “Files
>   and folders” from the “Service
>   receives selected” popup-menu, and
>   choose "Finder" from the “in” pop-up
>   menu.
>
> If you want selected text overwritten
>   with text modified in the workflow,
>   select the “Replaces selected text”
>   checkbox.
>
> Click the Finder plug-in workflow
>   window to bring it to the front.
>
> To copy all the actions in the
>   workflow, choose Edit > Select All,
>   and then choose Edit > Copy.
>
> Click the new service workflow window
>   to bring it to the front.
>
> Choose Edit > Paste.

Here is another detailed description of the process, with screenshots :
[Updating Finder Workflows in SnowLeopard](http://cecily.info/2009/08/30/updating-finder-workflows-in-snowleopard/).

For some more examples see : 
[3 Easy-To-Create Simple Automator Workflows For Everyday Use](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-easytocreate-simple-automator-workflows-everyday/).